# Обработка прерываный с помощью контроллера прерываний

Tags: алгоритм, ассемблер, прерывания

мне нужно знать полный алгоритм обработки прерываний, в интернете нашел этот алгоритм, он правильный? Если нет, то как будет правильно?

1. Запрос запоминается в регистре IRR
2. Игнорируются все запросы, которые замаскированы в регистре IMR
3. Если имеется хотя бы один запрос, берётся запрос с наивысшим приоритетом и сравнивается с регистром ISR, на то, с каким приоритетом сейчас выполняется прерывания
4. Если приоритет прерывания оказался больше, подаётся сигнал процессору и ожидается ответ
5. Получив ответ сбрасывается бит в IRR c высоким приоритетом и устанавливается соответствующий в ISR
6. Отправляется код прерывания процессору
7. По окончанию прерывания сбрасывается бит в ISR

Comment: На ассемблере все так и происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанные действия делает оборудование.
В обработке прерывания нужно сделать как можно быстрее необходимые действия и указать, что прерывание обработано. 
Для LAPIC следует записать ноль по адресу, указанному по смещению 0x2C от базы LAPIC, указанной в MSR 0x1B
См. [APIC](https://wiki.osdev.org/APIC) и [EOI Register](https://wiki.osdev.org/APIC#EOI_Register) в частности.

Comment: А можно узнать как происходит сравнение регистров IRR и ISR, я имею ввиду какая операция при этом производится?

Comment: Программисту это не должно быть интересно. Это уже для разработчиков железа. Про LAPIC  я уже написал, а в случае LegacyPIC нужно использовать последовательность команд `mov al,20h
out 20h,al` для первичного контроллера и `mov al, 20h
out A0h, al
out 20h, al` для вторичного. Для программных прерываний достаточно iret